# Setting file pointer position

Tags: c++, file

- I have a very large text file containing a number of entries arranged in lines.
- The first word of each line is like a "**key**" for me. The other words of the line are numbers.
- The first word of a line can exist in a large number of other lines as well.

As an example consider a sample of the file as follows :

```
Associative 19 78 45 23 
Disjunctive 23 45 02 200
Associative 23 546 32 56
Conjunctive 22 22 00 3478
Disjunctive 11 934 88 34
```

**My aim :**

Do a certain set of operations for all "Associatives", "Disjunctives" and "Conjunctives". The file is very large and is not sorted. I can do an additional operation of sort using bash, but just consider the case where I would like to avoid it.

**My approach** :

```
Step 1 : Open the file using **std::ifstream**
Step 2 : Create an unordered set to store the unique first words.
Step 3 : Create a multimap of type multimap<std::string,streampos>
Step 4 : Traverse the file using std::ifstream::ignore, and keep adding the first word to the unordered set, and stream position to the multimap alongwith the first word.
Step 5 : The thought is that in this way a primary index of stream position and line numbers is being created.
Step 6 : Now go through each element of the unordered set and use multimap::equal_range to look for stream positions for that key.
Step 7 : Traverse through those stream positions and do your operation
```

Q1. Is this approach correct to read a specific line from a file using C++ ?

Q2. Following is a basic snippet of the C++ program that I wrote to test this idea. However I do not find the idea to succeed. The program is complete. You can simply copy and paste the code and use the above sample of a text file to see the output. Specifically the problem is as follows :
When I set the stream position using seekg and then try to read a line, it seems that nothing happens (i.e the stream position is not changed).
The code snippet is as follows :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<limits>
#include<unordered_set>
#include<map>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
        if (argc<2)
        {
                cout<<"Usage: get_negatives <Full Path of Annotation File> \n"<<endl;
                return 0;
        }

        ifstream fileGT; 
        fileGT.open(argv[1]);//Open the file containing groundtruth annotations
        string filename;
        unordered_set<string> unique_files; //Open this unordered set to uniquely store the file names
        multimap<string,streampos> file_lines; //Open this multimap to store the file names as keys and corresponding line numbers as the values
        streampos filepos = fileGT.tellg();
        fileGT>>filename; 
        unique_files.insert(filename);
        file_lines.insert(pair<string,streampos>(filename,filepos));
        while(!fileGT.eof())
        {
                fileGT.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
                filepos = fileGT.tellg();       
                fileGT>>filename;
                unique_files.insert(filename);
                file_lines.insert(pair<string,streampos >(filename,filepos));
        }

        for(auto it=unique_files.begin(); it!=unique_files.end(); ++it)
        {
                pair<multimap<string,streampos>::iterator, multimap<string,streampos>::iterator>range_vals;
                range_vals = file_lines.equal_range(*it);
                for(auto it2=range_vals.first; it2!=range_vals.second; ++it2)
                {
                        fileGT.seekg(it2->second,ios_base::beg);
                        getline(fileGT,filename);       
                        cout<<filename<<endl;
                }
        }


        return -1;

}
```

Comment: You should really open the file as `std::ios_base::binary` if you are going to seek around.

Comment: Made the change, but the result did not change

Comment: How large is large?  Larger than available system memory?

Comment: Not really. Let us say 200-300 MB. But i am trying to write an efficient way of accessing a file by line

Comment: Operations to/from disk are (in my experience) slower than loading the file into memory (as values/int/double/etc or even mapping the file to memory).  You could try (once your above program works) comparing it to loading the entire file into memory.

Comment: Are you using C++11 or an earlier variant?  You could try adding `fileGT.clear();` after the first while loop just in case.  Or perhaps add it before calling `seekg` just in case `getline` sets a fail bit.

Comment: You should also check that the file was opened correctly in the first place and perhaps add checks whenever you read or perform operations on the file stream.

Comment: A whole bunch of small random reads don't seem very likely to be efficient to me. You're giving up the ability to use a small number of large, aligned reads (or a memory mapped file) and you aren't getting very much back for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `seekg()` sometimes does not work properly if some of the error bits are set.

You must always call `fileGT.clear()` before each `fileGT.seekg()`. I think that is supposed to be the default mode in C++11, but I wouldn't bet on that.

Also, it is a good idea to check for errors after each read:

```
if (!getline(fileGT, filename))
    //error handling
```

And, as I said in the comments, if you are going to seek around, you must open the file with `std::ios::binary`.

Comment: Instead of get line you can use **` file.ignore(<size>, <delimiter>)`**,

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested your code but here are a few changes I would recommend:

- Most operating systems I have encountered use the convention, for return value from main, `return 0` for typical/correct output and `return 1` (or non-zero) for anomalous cases.
- Don't use `\n` and `endl` unless you really need to, I don't think here is one of thouse cases.
- Consider reordering your `while` loop so the `ignore` is at the end, consider the following:

.

```
std::string buf;
std::ifstream fp("input");
while (fp)
{
  if (fp >> buf) { /* do something with buf */ }
  fp.ignore(streamsize::max(), '\n');
}
```

- Whenever you read from a stream don't assume the output is good or the stream is still valid.  Check the error flags (using the bool overload or `fp.good()`).  Just checking `fp.eof()` may not always be enough.
- If you are using C++11 `seekg` *should* run fine even after you reach the end of file however in earlier variants you will need to clear the stream error bits using `fp.clear()`.
- If you arn't compiling with C++11 the `auto` keyword may not do what you think it does, be careful.  You might also want to consider `const auto&`.